# A date column in a table won't save the value after a correct date was entered

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, date

I have a table with a column named `Shipped Date`. It is declared as a column of type `DATE` and retains NULL marks by default.

When I "edited" other columns in the table it worked, but when I entered in a standard date value such as '9/14/2017' into the `Shipped Date` column, the DBMS will let me enter it but it won't save it after I press <kbd>TAB</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

I edited `Shipped Date` directly in the table. I also tried to enter "2017-14-09" and "September 09, 2017" into the column, but it still won't save it.

I put in the date with a format of "07-APR-9"8, and then I click the *Commit* button, and an error message popped up that said:

> Could not save file table ORDERS.

`Tools/Preferences/Database/NLS/Date Format` has `DD-MON-RR`.

Is RR supposed to be year? If I wanted it in `month-Date-Year` then I suppose that it will be `MON-DD-RR`. Is that correct? I did put it in the format of `DD-MON-RR` (15-09-17) but it still does not work.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 17.2.0.188.

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

There are loads of options/possibilities. See [Datetime Format Models](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212) in the Database SQL Language Reference.

For example, if you have it set to `DD-MON-RR`, you should use `15-SEP-17`.

`RR` lets you store 20th century dates in the 21st century using only two digits, as described in [The RR Datetime Format Element](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#i116004):

> The `RR` datetime format element is similar to the `YY` datetime format element, but it provides additional flexibility for storing date values in other centuries. The `RR` datetime format element lets you store 20th century dates in the 21st century by specifying only the last two digits of the year.
>
> If you use the `TO_DATE` function with the `YY` datetime format element, then the year returned always has the same first 2 digits as the current year. If you use the `RR` datetime format element instead, then the century of the return value varies according to the specified two-digit year and the last two digits of the current year.
>
> That is:
>
> - If the specified two-digit year is 00 to 49, then
>
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 greater than the first 2 digits of the current year.
> - If the specified two-digit year is 50 to 99, then
>
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 00 to 49, then the first 2 digits of the returned year are 1 less than the first 2 digits of the current year.
>   - If the last two digits of the current year are 50 to 99, then the returned year has the same first two digits as the current year.

Answer (score 1):

The way I avoid all the silly Oracle problems with updating/inserting `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE` columns is to always provide my preferred ( SANE ) format and convert it using `TO_TIMESTAMP()` and `TO_DATE()` every time!

I prefer to use `ISO-8601` formats in `UTC` because that is the only universally sane format to use.

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(?,'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"')
TO_DATE(?, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Where the `?` is either a literal or a placeholder for replacement with a string in the correct format.

This avoids arguments with DBA's about changing database wide settings they many of them do not even know how to make most of the time. It puts you in control of the format you prefer to work with and avoids conflicts with those dictating silly rules for no other reason than ignorance or convenience for them.